# Show data content object as grid view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How to show list of data objects as a grid. A data object include information about a person. It's not difficult to show it in a table but now how to show in grid as thumbnail

Comment: Whats the difference between a grid and a table in your case?

Comment: A object can have some long content. It's not good if I show in table

Comment: Fair enough but a grid IS a table! Thumbnails are images so I don't think thats the right term if what you are displaying is content. I am guessing that what you are trying to do is to truncate content that is over a certain length? I am sure there is a filter for that. If you can confirm that this is what you are trying to do I will check and get back to you.